# Object has no attribute error on MVC like Python project

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting "MainView has no atribute ct", even though it is being set on its `__init__`

ct would be the reference to the controller

Here's MainView.py

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainView(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, ct):
        tk.Frame.__init__(root)
        self.startUI()
        self.ct = ct

    def startUI(self):

        botaoProdutos = tk.Button(self, text = "Produtos", command = self.toProdutos() , padx = 5 , pady = 5)
        botaoProdutos.pack(side = "top")

    def toProdutos(self):
        self.ct.toProdutos()


def start(ct):
    ct = ct
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root, ct)
    main.tkraise()
    root.mainloop()
    return main
```

And the caller

```
from Controller.ProdutoController import ProdutoController
from View.MainView import start

class Main:
    def __start__(self):

        self.ctProduto = ProdutoController()

        self.viewMain = start(self)

    def toProdutos(self):

        self.ctProduto.toProdutos()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.__start__()
```

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gabriel/PycharmProjects/untitled/Controller/Main.py", line 19, in <module>
    main.__start__()
  File "C:/Users/Gabriel/PycharmProjects/untitled/Controller/Main.py", line 9, in __start__
    self.viewMain = start(self)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\untitled\View\MainView.py", line 22, in start
    main = MainView(root, ct)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\untitled\View\MainView.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.startUI()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\untitled\View\MainView.py", line 12, in startUI
    botaoProdutos = tk.Button(self, text = "Produtos", command = self.toProdutos() , padx = 5 , pady = 5)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\untitled\View\MainView.py", line 16, in toProdutos
    self.ct.toProdutos()
```

Comment: When is the error thrown (i.e. when making what function call)? Do you have the exact error/stack trace?

Comment: @nbryans in method toProdutos at self.ct.toProdutos()

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You have not shown the `ProdutoController` class, which is where your error originates.

Comment: @cricket_007 traceback doesn't even gets there, I edited it

Comment: I was thinking it was because the class is a tk.Frame, and tk.Frame has no attribute "ct", but it should be possible to create one

Comment: I believe you never pass the `ProdutoController` from `Main` into `MainView`. All you assigned was the `root` parameter. Therefore `ct` is `None`

Comment: Besides, your button should have `command = self.toProdutos` (remove the parenthesis)

Comment: @cricket_007 that changed the error to "MainView" has no attribute tk and the error traces to that same button creation

Answer (score 0):

Few things I see that you are missing.

1. Need to put the button into the `root`.

```
botaoProdutos = tk.Button(self.root, text="Produtos", command=self.toProdutos, padx=5, pady=5)
```

To do that, you need to add `self.root = root` to the `__init__`.

2. You'll also want to initialize the `super` object correctly, so that's why `tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)` is there.

```
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
```

Now, in typically MVC, your view should not be handed the controller, so I suggest, you restructure your app like so, for example

```
class ProdutoController():
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.model = model
        self.view = view

        self.view.register(self)

    def toProdutos(self):
        print(self.model.name) # TODO: Replace
```

And the changes to the View look like this

```
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.startUI()
        self.ct = None

    def register(self, ct):
        self.ct = ct
```

And finally, the `main` or `start` function, can assign the Model and View to the Controller

```
root = tk.Tk()

model = Produto("StackOverflow")
view = MainView(root)

ct = ProdutoController(model, view)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why does the button have to be in the root window? I think the rest of your answer is OK, but I think that first part is bad advice.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I actually got the button to display when I did that, otherwise it was an empty pane. While I agree, that seemed to be the quickest solution rather than searching for that reason

Comment: The quickest solution, in this case, is wrong. The button doesn't appear because the window it is in is never packed/placed/gridded.